My 3D printer's extruder doesn't work
I have a longer LK5 Pro that I bought few years ago but didn't use that much (233h printing time)
Since few days I noticed this problem that doesn't allow me to print anymore. Basically, the gears that push the filament into the extruder push the filament a bit then go back.
I am unable to upload the video in here so I uploaded it into youtube,
the video might add some details into my description, so here's the link to the video
Could anyone please help me solve this?

Your extruder stepper is skipping because there is too much friction down to the hotend. This implies you have an obstruction somewhere.

Start by checking if the filament can be pushed into the head - there seems to be a blockage.
Heat up the hot end and then pull out the fillament backward through the bowden tube and extruder.  It should come out smoothly with minimal force.   There should be no lumps other than perhaps a melty pointed bit on the tip.
If you have a blockage in the nozzle, try poking a very thin wire up inside.  Your printer may have come with one.  Be mindful of the heat.  If there's a larger obstruction behind, then you may have to remove the nozzle by unthreading it while it is warm.
Also, try doing a levelling of the bed.  I have found that if my nozzle is too low, and scraping on the bed then that's enough resistance that the extruder can't push filament.

Excellent, I would add: "Raise the gantry first to prevent extra pressure against the bed."
